# How to keep the same amount of people based on a column in SAS Guide?

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

Imagine this is what I have:

```
id  x   y    z     target
1   a   b    c          1
1   a   b    c          1
1   a   b    c          1
2   a   b    c          0
2   a   b    c          0
3   a   b    c          0
4   a   b    c          0
4   a   b    c          0
5   a   b    c          1
5   a   b    c          1 
6   a   b    c          0
6   a   b    c          0
6   a   b    c          0
7   a   b    c          0
7   a   b    c          0
```

What I need is to keep the same amount of IDs (and its rows) based on the target variable, randomly, so I have a balanced dataset to create a predictive model.

In this example we have 2 IDs with target 1 and 5 IDs with target 0, so it is a not balanced dataset based on the target variable. My original dataset is composed by 1142 IDs with target 1 and 8395 IDs with target 0.

I want to keep the dataset as big as possible, so, to keep the same amount of IDs for each value of the target variable, the output would be, for example, 2 IDs with target 1 (which are in disadvantage) and 2 IDs with target 0.
And I said randomly because there are no further rules to filter who with target 1 is being kept.

I have been searching but can't seem to find anything similar. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just use PROC SURVEYSELECT with SIZE= option.

Calculate the size of the smallest group and use that as the SIZE= option.

Here is example using SASHELP.CLASS as dataset and SEX as the stratifying variable.

```
proc sort data=sashelp.class out=have;
  by sex;
run;

proc sql noprint;
select min(count) into :size 
  from (select sex,count(*) as count from have group by sex)
;
quit;
%put &=size;


proc surveyselect data=have n=&size seed=47279 out=want;
  strata sex;
run;
```

Comment: thank you for the help and sorry for the delay, but it did not resulted in what I wanted. 
I can't seem to 100% understand what happened but I think the output is returning 50% rows with target 0 and 50% rows with target 1, but that is not what I need. 
I need to have a output with 50% IDS that have target 0 and 50% IDS that have target 1, mantaining all rows of those ids.

Comment: If the same id appears multiple times you need first get a list of distinct id values and sample from that.  You can then use the sampled ids to subset the original dataset.